# How to generate random duration value of second argument ( duration) in setInterval function

Tags: javascript

How to generate random duration value of second argument ( duration) in setInterval function.

```
 //such as



 var timerId = setInterval( timer_counter,getRandomInt(5,60),number,slatt);
```

Comment: What is the implementation of getRandomInt?

Comment: [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)?

Comment: If you are asking how to implement getRandomInt, there is an implementation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Are you asking how to make the interval random each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var n = 10, // max value
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1; // random number (1-10)
setInterval(function(){
  timer_counter();
}, r * 1000); // to milliseconds
```

You're looking for [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) I believe (coupled with `Math.floor`).

*Note:* If `r` is (for example) 3, it will execute *every 3 seconds* for the life of that interval. If you want it to change, you need to use a `setTimeout` and change the timeout on every call. So to do that:

```
function worker(){
  // the code that should be executed
}
function repeat(){
  var n = 10; // every 1-10 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){
    worker();
    repeat();
  }, (Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1) * 1000);
}();
```

And to give you that `getRandomInt` function:

```
function getRandomInt(nMax, nMin){
  nMax = nMax || 10;
  nMin = nMin || 0;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (nMax - nMin + 1)) + nMin;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot Brad Christie. But i want to change duration parameter of setInterval after each interval.

Comment: Actuaaly i want to change second parameter (second parameter means time duration in millisecond ) of setTimeout or setInterval  method   On runtime. Suppose i have one array like that  ['1-5','5-10','10-15','15-20'] Now i want generate random time interval among these array element.

Comment: In second code block (Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1) * 1000)  suppose above code  generate random number 6 then it repeat

Comment: @ Brad Christie: Thanks a lot for help. finally i have completed my task.